# Navigational drop-down lists in Wordpress?

Tags: navigation, forms, e-commerce

I'm trying to simplify a set of links by placing them in a drop down list (form style) with a submit button that will take users to the page in question.

Ideally, I'd like it to behave like the drop-down lists on [RedBubble](http://www.redbubble.com/products/configure/5867346-t-shirt/) where each selection is also associated with a different image.

As a newbie to Wordpress and web development in general, I suspect that this may be more of a general coding question than Wordpress specific, but I'm hoping maybe there's a plug in that could help with this. However, if the solution is css or javascript based, I'm more than happy to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you on your way, a similar question was asked just a couple of days ago [**Colour Selection With Thumbnails**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/wordpress-shop-enable-custormers-to-select-product-color-using-image-thumbnails), you'l probably need to get a grip on how javascript works using id's as a selector